# Autoload related race condition in Cucumber with AJAX requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using Cucumber with capybara-webkit for my app's integration tests on Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.1. A handful of test in my cucumber test suite unexpectedly began spitting out errors like this:

```
  Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant UiValidators::ParameterFinder (RuntimeError)
  /Users/kingp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@triquest/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:484:in `load_missing_constant'
  /Users/kingp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@triquest/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
  /Users/kingp/Projects/rails-triquest/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ContactsController>'
  /Users/kingp/Projects/rails-triquest/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/kingp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@triquest/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  ...
```

The error says 'circular dependency', but it is actually thrown at any time the Rails autoloader tries to load a constant that is already in its set of loaded constants. Typically this is indeed due to a circular dependency, but I'm pretty sure that's not the case in my app. A diff between the branch with the crashing test and the stable branch I forked from shows that the only changes are to coffeescript files, view templates, a migration, and the new cucumber features I was writing. I haven't touched any controller or model code.

I ended up inserting some logging code into the rails autoloader to help me figure out what's going on:

```
  # Inserted at activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:467
  _thread_id_for_debug = Thread.current.object_id
  STDERR.puts "*** #{loaded.count} #{from_mod} #{const_name} - #{_thread_id_for_debug}"
```

`loaded` is a set of paths to autoloaded code files, `from_mod` the context where the request came from, `const_name` the constant we're trying to load. Which all ultimately got me this, immediately before the crash:

```
  *** 104 Object SitesController - 70180261360940
  *** 105 Object ContactsController - 70180240113760
  *** 105 SitesController UiValidators - 70180261360940
  *** 105 Object UiValidators - 70180261360940
  *** 105 UiValidators ParameterFinder - 70180261360940
  *** 107 UiValidators ParameterFinder - 70180240113760
```

It looks like two threads are attempting to autoload the same constant. My guess is that the name of the constant is added to Rails' set of 'loaded' constants by the first thread before it has finished loading. The second thread can't resolve the constant (since the load hasn't finished yet), asks the autoloader to find it, and the autoloader raises when it sees the constant in its 'loaded' set.

At this point in the test, two controllers (SitesController and ContactsController) are responding to AJAX requests, launched nearly simultaneously.

I have found a way to work around the crash, by just including a reference to the module `UiValidators::ParameterFinder` ahead of the AJAX. But this seems fragile, and also not very elegant. Short of turning on eager loading for the test environment, is there any other way to avoid this problem?

Comment: i'm having same problem. turning eager_load on didn't even fix it for me .. don't understand why not because it shouldn't be trying to autoload at all with that enabled? still debugging ..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (without Cucumber, just Capybara & Poltergeist). setting `config.eager_load = true` didn't even work for me (don't quite understand why not..).

I ended up using [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) and haven't had a circular dependency error since.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Rails 4.1.4 when using Sidekiq. I assume that a race condition inside the threaded Sidekiq workers caused all kinds of hijinks when `const_missing` inside **active_support** was called.

In addition to make sure that my current environment would perform eager loading i.e. via `config.eager_load = true` I also had to add all components that my workers were using from the `lib` directory into `config.eager_load_paths` (via `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` inside `config/application.rb`).

This was necessary because I assume that setting `config.eager_load = true` only makes Rails eager load the contents of the `app/` directory.

```
App::Application.config.eager_load_paths
=> [
  [0] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/assets",
  [1] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/controllers",
  [2] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/helpers",
  [3] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/mailers",
  [4] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/models",
  [5] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/services",
  [6] "/home/archive/releases/20140721180504/app/workers"
]
```

The combination of both seemed to have helped with the issue.